# Pagination using custom payloads option with Java driver 3.1 and Cassandra

Tags: pagination, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using cassansra 3.7 and Java Driver 3.1. i have written a java code to connect cassandra and fetch data from database.

I found that pagination will be possible using custom payload option by following this url  http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/custom_payloads/

But i did not find any example to use custom payloads to achieve pagination.

Can anybody please let me know how to use this option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Custom payloads are not used for pagination. They only mention paging there as a note on how custom payloads are handled during paging. Custom payloads are only used when you're integrating with a custom QueryHandler on the server side.

Paging is done implicitly by the driver. Please see the documentation [here](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/paging/) for paging with the java driver.

Comment: Thank you very much. may i know for which purpose we will use QueryHandler.i referred paging documentation --- here they have used extractPagingStateStringFromURL(). to use this method, is i need to include any jar or i need to extend any predefined class.

Comment: i think extractPagingStateStringFromURL(),renderInResponse(),renderNextPageLink() are should define by us with respective coding right?

Comment: I have done with pagination using paging concept. is there any predefined function to get previous page like getting nextpage.if not then how we will navigate to previous page . the link that you have suggested contains only to navigate next page.can you please let me know.

Comment: [ResultSet.getExecutionInfo](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/PagingIterable.html#getExecutionInfo--) has a [PagingState that can be obtained](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/ExecutionInfo.html#getPagingState--) and set onto a subsequent Statement.

Comment: Yes that is to get next page link right? i have done with that. now i need to navigate to previous page. is there any way to get previous page link?

Comment: You would have needed to save the paging state from the previous page.

Comment: Yes i am trying with that option only.